# How to stop TF2 from crashing when attempting to play Invasion maps?

Tags: technical-issues, team-fortress-2

I can play and host other maps just fine, but whenever I try to play the 2015 Halloween event, Invasion, the map loads to about 80% and then `hl2.exe` crashes.

I made sure to have enough free RAM and HDD space, and verified my cache.

```
64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium on Intel i5 750 @2.67GHz
NVIDIA GeForce GT 220 (driver 9.18.13.4181) OpenGL 3.3
Primary Display Resolution: 1680 x 1050
Primary VRAM: 1024 MB
RAM: 12279 MB
Total Hard Disk Space Available: 9,52 GB
```

Despite my solutions below, 2fort Invasion still crashes while sending client info with one loading bar left. Watergate, Probed, and Byre work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE 2**: Using [launch option](http://etf2l.org/forum/customise/topic-16829/) `-dx98` in Steam's game properties, I was able to play `ctf_2fort_invasion`! Trying with `CRLF` line endings in `autoexec.cfg` failed, as did `1440x900`. Launch option `-condebug` only shows `Redownloading all lightmaps` as last line, and lately some warnings:

```
*** Encountered VTF file with an invalid minor version!
*** Encountered VTF file with an invalid full header!
Error reading texture header "materials/vgui/resource/mic_meter_live.vtf"
```

I revalidated my local TF2 files: no errors.

**UPDATE:** Without a `CR` character in `autoexec.cfg`, Watergate works fine in high res! Open it in [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [other decent editor](http://www.sublimetext.com/), and convert line endings to `LF`-only ("Unix-style").

Old solution:

I first renamed `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Team Fortress 2\tf\cfg\autoexec.cfg` to `autoexec.cfg.2014`. This allowed me to auto-join an Invasion multiplayer arena game. It never got enough players, so I can't verify actual gameplay, but at least the map loaded fully. Other Invasion game modes still had the same crashing problem, though.

I then changed my video resolution from `1440x900` to `1280x768`. That did the trick, and I spent a few hours playing without any technical issue.

[image: Working TF2 Invasion resolution]

This was my `autoexec.cfg`, with `CRLF` on line 1:

```
tf_bot_quota 4; tf_bot_quota_mode fill
bind "F9" "sv_cheats 1; echo Generating navigation data...; nav_generate; sv_cheats 0"
```

Trying to play with this cfg and lower res works on Byre arena, but crashes while loading the Watergate player destruction map.

Comment: Is there something in your 2014 config specifically that caused the crash? Did you try Verifying the Integrity of the Game Cache through Steam?

Comment: I've updated my posts, and will try again with the `cfg`.

Comment: It's definitely either one that causes problems.

Comment: Weird that the CR char would cause problems.

Comment: Indeed, also that 2fort Invasion still crashes with one loading bar left. :(

Comment: On a related note, the other new Halloween maps stopped crashing when i moved a custom hud+model to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Team Fortress 2\tf\custom\disabled`

Comment: which do you use? ToonHUD had an update within a couple of days that fixed some issues with Halloween

Comment: @Robotnik I was using `character models-scout-scootaloo~rainbow dash scout model by kassgrein-2012.09.01` VPKs.